# Human leukocytes (re)circulation/migration in homeostatic state

Tags: immunology, blood-circulation, homeostasis, immunity

One can easily find information on the topic of leukocytes trafficking between vessels and peripheral tissues during inflammation.

But what happens during normal states when there is no pathology? Do all the subtypes of granulocytes, monocytes, and lymphocytes leave the blood vessels and enter healthy tissues in the same way they do under pathological (inflammatory) conditions?

References and thoughts are very welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Which leukocytes do you mean? Peripheral memory b cells?

Comment: I have edited your question a bit. Please feel free to roll back if you think it alters your question.